# Swagger-CodeGen Marker for Package in Java Code generation

Tags: java, package, swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I'm using the Swagger Maven Plugin ([GitHub](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin)).
Is it possible for this, the CodeGen itself or another tool for Swagger to add a Marker in the YAML-file that decides which package the class should go?

Or the other way around is it possible to change the package structure of the generated code without creating a new template?